# 403 Forbibben in API Rest Call

Tags: java, rest

I am writing a small program in java which makes a rest call to an endpoint to verify a reference id. I have written this program in two different ways and each work when I run it from my PC but when I deploy the jar file on the test `Linux CentOs Server`, I get a `403 forbidden error` from the end point, So I thought maybe the ip was blocked and then I tried the same thing with curl and it worked perfectly.

What could be the issue? could it be ssl certificate version error?

Way 1 :

```
public String sendGet(String id) {
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    log.info("Authorization :::: {}", "Bearer " + this.getApiAuth());

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.getApiAuth());

    List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();

    acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<String> httpRequestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> exchange = getRestTemplate().exchange(this.getUrl() + id, HttpMethod.GET, httpRequestEntity, String.class);

    log.info("Status Code :::: {}", exchange.getStatusCode());
    log.info("Status Code :::: {}", exchange.getBody());
    return exchange.getBody(); 
}
```

Way 2 :

```
 public String sendGet(String message) throws Exception {
    infoLogger.info("GOING HERE " + url + message);

    java.lang.System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
    URL obj = new URL(url + message);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    infoLogger.info("Setting Authorization: Bearer " + this.getApiAuth());
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " +this.getApiAuth());
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    con.setRequestProperty("accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    infoLogger.info("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    infoLogger.info("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = null;
    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    if ((200 <= con.getResponseCode()) && (con.getResponseCode() <= 299)) {
        if (con.getInputStream() != null) {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        }
    } else if (con.getErrorStream() != null) {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream()));
    } else {
        infoLogger.info("GOT NOTHING ");
    }

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());
    return response.toString();

}
```

So I did a `.getResponseMessage` as asked and I got the following error:

> Access denied | api.paystack.co used Cloudflare to restrict accessbody{margin:0;padding:0}      Please enable cookies.
>
> ## Error          1010          Ray ID: 49f12b9b9bb6c5fa • 2019-01-26 07:12:17 UTC
>
> Access denied                                                What happened?
>
> The owner of this website (api.paystack.co) has banned your access based on your browser's signature (49f12b9b9bb6c5fa-ua21).
>
> Cloudflare Ray ID: **49f12b9b9bb6c5fa**    •    Your IP: 104.248.9.123    •    Performance & security by Cloudflare
>
> window._cf_translation = {};    `

Comment: If curl works, did you try --verbose or --trace to see detail information about https handshake, version, certificate etc.?

Comment: @JensDibbern  SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

Comment: And you are using java.lang.System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"); If the server wants to enforce TLSv1.3, this may be your problem.

Comment: @JensDibbern if I remove that portion of code. I get an ssl exception

Comment: What about System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.3");? You will need Java 11 to use TLSv1.3. And you could try curl with --tlsv1.2 option to verify that the server really needs v1.3.

Comment: @JensDibbern so I forced --tlsv from 1.1 to 1.2 and the server responsed with valid data on  curl. I checked the java version running on the CentOs and it is `openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-0ubuntu0.18.10.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)` What could be the problem because my jvm is up to date and should carry all the tlsv versions.

Comment: So TLS version seems not to be an issue and unauthorized would be 401 instead of 403. Is there anything else in the response? You could call getResponseMessage(). And do you have access to server logs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187353/discussion-between-alex-davies-and-jens-dibbern).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The supplyer of the service you are trying to access is using CloudFlare. They are using some sort of browser integrity check (see https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171806-Error-1010-The-owner-of-this-website-has-banned-your-access-based-on-your-browser-s-signature).

You can change the signature in your java code:

```
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "My own REST client");
```

You seem to use a different JDK on your PC than on your CentOS server, so the signatures of the Java HttpsURLConnection are different. They are of course different from curl.

Comment: So where you set the “My own REST client” I can generate a Unique Identity Number and set it in there?

Comment: You can try it like above. Just add addtional unique numbers if it still does not work.

Comment: Neither the company which service I am consuming knew about it.

Answer (score 2):

For Way 1, this will work:

```
headers.add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");
```