# How to CORS bypass in Spring?

Tags: spring-boot

I create applications - API client in Spring Boot with RestTemplate.
The API (not mine) probably has CORS, besouce in console I get 403, but in browser/postman is ok.
How to bypass CORS?

```
public Pokemontcg getPokemontcg() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Pokemontcg forObject = restTemplate.getForObject("https://api.pokemontcg.io/v1/cards?name=charizard", Pokemontcg.class);
    return forObject;
}
```

Result

> "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden

Comment: Where you’re getting the CORS error ?

Comment: update your question with a little bit of code

Comment: the request is working fine from curl. You should check the complete error response once. The API is being protected using cloudflare. You might find a solution in the question below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54367327/403-forbibben-in-api-rest-call

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ays. One of the most efficient is 
doing it in `JavaConfig`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

Or the simplest ways is 
**Controller Method CORS Configuration**
Enabling CORS is straightforward – just add the annotation @CrossOrigin.

We may implement this in a number of different ways.

`@CrossOrigin` on a `@RequestMapping-Annotated` Handler Method

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    public Account retrieve(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }
```

If you want client-side solution here is the solution

Consider this example.

Your server is my-server.com and your client is my-client.com Configure `nginx` as follows:

```
// nginx.conf

upstream server {
    server my-server.com;
}

upstream client {
    server my-client.com;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name my-website.com;
    access_log /path/to/access/log/access.log;
    error_log /path/to/error/log/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client;
    }

    location ~ /server/(?<section>.*) {
        rewrite ^/server/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://server;
    }
}
```

Here `my-website.com` will be the resultant name of the website where the code will be accessible (name of the proxy website). Once `nginx` is configured this way. You will need to modify the requests such that:

```
All API calls change from my-server.com/<API-path> to my-website.com/server/<API-path>
```

Comment: But this is not my API. I only create a API client.

Comment: Yes, you can simply change @requestmapping as there was very less info in your question. This is very generic example.

Comment: CORS: Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. When you talk to 2 different servers then it comes. Both the servers need to trust each other so you just need to whitelist URLs. From where you are coming.

In registry.addMapping("/**"); you can add your client URLs or there is another bit complicated solution that is called reverse proxy. I am assuming the project is very small.

Comment: But I am not the author of the API and I cannot add my client. That is why I ask how bypass it?

Comment: The server is responsible for reporting the allowed origins. The web browser is responsible for enforcing that requests are only sent from allowed domains. However, it is possible. Can you please share which pl you are using on your client-side?

Comment: i use Spring/Java

Comment: I am confused. How can you make a client using Spring!!! Can you please update question correctly. I updated my answer, see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, boi you have an absolutely different issue. It is not something bad with your code.

Read this thread https://github.com/simonprickett/allthepokemon/issues/1

Per this please change your endpoint to `http://pokeapi.salestock.net/api/v2/`

If this also doesn't help use `https://cors.now.sh/https://your_URL`.

`https://cors.now.sh` enables reverse proxy and with absolute URLs will definitely work.

That's quite a weird solution but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component

public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleCORSFilter.class);

public SimpleCORSFilter() {
    log.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

}
```